# Is a good practice looping a test?

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

I am having a test that checks the response from an API route, but basically more of the same kind of routes will be added.

The routes only change like this:

1. /example/route/`red`
2. /example/route/`green`

I am creating an array of strings:

```
const ending = [
 "red",
 "green"
]
```

Then I loop into the array and use the same `describe` method to test this functionality

```
ending.forEach(end => {
  describe(`${end} routes`, () => {
    // My test goes here  
  }
}
```

Is working, but the question is if this is a good practice in testing?

Or if this could cause an unexpected behaviour later?

Thanks!

Comment: @Jb31 OP is doing the loop *around* the test

Comment: If the endpoints all return the same result and the test is testing what you want then it's fine, but if you start to have to put lots of logic in the test to handle diff results then no.

Comment: Why the -1 point? is not a valid question? let me know to avoid this kind of questions for the community. But please explain the reason.

Thanks @LawrenceCherone makes sense